# Why am I might be able to login with ssh to another server without password?

Tags: ssh, login

I am new admin for those servers after one guy left the job. I have to make sure everything is secure.

I tried in one server lets call it A to enter:

```
ssh [hostname of B server] -p [port]
```

and I am logged in to B after entering passphrase. I want to know why I might be able to login? 
I searched in B for authorized_keys, and I found one but it was empty file. So if it is empty I assume nobody should be allowed to login using private key.

But I probably do not know something.

So if somebody cracks server A and knows the passphrase, then he is able to login to server B currently.

**Update:**

Ok, after I tried opening the same authorized_keys file with sudo, then I see its not empty. Why it is mistaking me then?

Comment: Which user does the authorized keys file belong to?

Comment: @Arronical - I do not want to publicly tell user and make it easier to crack. But lets call it user_on_B . And btw I disable password login for this user. The authorized_keys file is in user_on_B home directory .ssh folder.
And in authorized_keys file at the end I see user_on_B_2@user_on_B_2 which password I also have disabled

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Yes, if there's an authorized key, the user can connect with no password if they've entered the passphrase. How is it mistaking you? What is the actual question?

Comment: Understandable that you don't want to reveal usernames! I'm having trouble following the question. If key based authentication is in place, then the passphrase for the key will get you in. If you disable password login, does that not mean the user can log in with no authentication?

Comment: yea, first I thought the authorized_keys file was empty. Its mistaking me that after entering sudo - it becomes not empty. So I am logging in as user in which home directory the file lies? And then when I tried to run sudo nano - it did not work, probably because I have disable password for that user. So he can connect,  but cannot run sudo commands as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I was able to login because authorized_keys file was not empty. 
It looked empty because first I run

```
nano authorized_keys
```

I mean without sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have a ssh config file. Here you can set different autologin actions, where to put the keys for accessing to the servers, etc.

This file can be found at '$HOME/.ssh/config'. If exists, here you have the key to connect.